# Disable "Search with Google" right click option in Intellij IDEA Ultimate

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

There is a **Search with Google** option in the right click menu in Intellij editor. I would like to disable it along with any shortcut keys mapped to it. I want to do this so as to avoid any accidental usage.
I'm using Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2020.3

Please advise how it can be done.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following steps.

> In the Settings/Preferences dialog `Ctrl+Alt+S`
>
> Select **Menus and Toolbars** from **Appreance & Behavior**
>
> search **google** in searchbar in the right [image]
>
> select **search on google**
>
> remove it by clicking on **remove symbol(-)** (**refer above image*)
>
> Apply the changes and close the dialog.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to remove it. Do you know if it's mapped to some shortcut key? I would like to remove it as well.

Comment: @Rahul by default there is no shortcut added for search with google